# Can apache flume hdfs sink accept dynamic path to write?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am new to apache flume.
I am trying to see how I can get a json (as http source), parse it and store it to a dynamic path on hdfs according to the content.
For example:
if the json is:

```
[{   
  "field1" : "value1",
  "field2" : "value2"
}]
```

then the hdfs path will be:
 /some-default-root-path/value1/value2/some-value-name-file
Is there such configuration of flume that enables me to do that?

Here is my current configuration (accepts a json via http, and stores it in a path according to timestamp):

```
#flume.conf: http source, hdfs sink

# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type =  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.r1.port = 9000
#a1.sources.r1.handler = org.apache.flume.http.JSONHandler

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/uri/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The solution was in the flume [documentation for the hdfs sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink):

Here is the revised configuration:

```
#flume.conf: http source, hdfs sink

# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type =  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.r1.port = 9000
#a1.sources.r1.handler = org.apache.flume.http.JSONHandler

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/uri/events/%{field1}
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

and the curl:

```
curl -X POST -d '[{  "headers" : {           "timestamp" : "434324343", "host" :"random_host.example.com", "field1" : "val1"            },  "body" : "random_body"  }]' localhost:9000
```

Comment: I am using a different source (RabbitMQ) and I am passing a JSON payload myself. The method you described seems to be not working in my case. I am assuming, something is wrong at my end unless you faced similar issues