# HDFS sink: "clever" folder routing

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am new to Flume (and to HDFS), so I hope my question is not stupid.

I have a multi-tenant application (about 100 different customers as for
now).
I have 16 different data types.

(In production, we have approx. 15 million messages/day through our
RabbitMQ)

I want to write to HDFS all my events, separated by tenant, data type,
and date, like this :

```
/data/{tenant}/{data_type}/2014/10/15/file-08.csv
```

Is it possible with one sink definition ? I don't want to duplicate
configuration, and new client arrive every week or so

In documentation, I see

```
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://server/events/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
```

Is this possible ?

```
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://server/events/%tenant/%type/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
```

I want to write to different folders according to my incoming data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can apache flume hdfs sink accept dynamic path to write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830147/can-apache-flume-hdfs-sink-accept-dynamic-path-to-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is indeed possible. You can either use the metadata or some field in the incoming data to redirect the output to.

For example, in my case I am getting different types of log data and I want to store it in respective folders accordingly. Also in my case the first word in my log lines is the file name. Here is the config snippet for the same.

Interceptor:

```
dataplatform.sources.source1.interceptors = i3
dataplatform.sources.source1.interceptors.i3.type = regex_extractor
dataplatform.sources.source1.interceptors.i3.regex = ^(\\w*)\t.*
dataplatform.sources.source1.interceptors.i3.serializers = s1
dataplatform.sources.source1.interceptors.i3.serializers.s1.name = filename
```

HDFS Sink

```
dataplatform.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
dataplatform.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://server/events/provider=%{filename}/years=%Y/months=%Y%m/days=%Y%m%d/hours=%H
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution may be to write an interceptor which passes the tenant value.

please refer to the link below

http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/flume-getting-started-with-interceptors/