# Writing to custom HDFS directory based on message data for Kafka -> Flume -> hdfs ingestion

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

How can I write to custom hdfs directory using flume based on message type  in Kafka message ?

Say kafka message: `{"type": "A", "data": "blah"}` having "A" in type field should be written to `/data/A`, message: `{"type": "B", "data": "blah"}` having "B" in type field should be written to `/data/B`, etc

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail and/or show what you've tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385035/hdfs-sink-clever-folder-routing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Custom flume sink.
[Apache Flume custom sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink)

Comment: Not just a custom Sink. To send events to a particular sink based on its content (called multiplexing ) , you will need a write an interceptor http://xingwu.me/2014/10/11/Routing-Flume-Events-to-Different-Sinks/